# How to make palindrome code not worry about the (userInput) word spacing

Tags: c++

as described in the title, I am having trouble with my code trying to read the spaces in between the words for example "never odd or even" returns as "never odd or even is not a palindrome" but its supposed to say "never odd or even is a palindrome". Below i will provide my current code and the grading results along with the numbers i cant seem to fix.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main() {
string userInput;
int startInput;
bool isPalindrome = true;

getline (cin, userInput);

startInput = userInput.length();

for (int i = 0; i<(startInput/2); i++){
if (userInput[i] != userInput[(startInput -1) -i])
isPalindrome = false; 
}
if (isPalindrome == true){
cout << userInput << " is a palindrome" << endl;
}
else {
cout << userInput << " is not a palindrome" <<endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

3:
Input: never odd or even
Your output: never odd or even is not a palindrome
Expected output: never odd or even is a palindrome

5:
Input: dr awkward
Your output: dr awkward is not a palindrome
Expected output: dr awkward is a palindrome

7: 
Input: no lemon no melon
Your output: no lemon no melon is not a palindrome
Expected output: no lemon no melon is a palindrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove spaces from the string, and that can be done with a single function call in C++ by utilizing [std::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

Next, compare the string that has the spaces removed with a reversed version of the string.  Another one liner by creating a string using reverse iterators:

So let's break this down:

1) Removing spaces from a string:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
//...
std::string s;
//...
s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), ::isspace), s.end());
```

2) Build a reversed version of a string:

```
   std::string s;
   // ... 
   std::string sreversed == std::string(s.rbegin(), s.rend());
```

3) Putting this all together into a neat function:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

bool isPalindrome(std::string s)
{
   // erase the spaces
   s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), ::isspace), s.end());

   // compare original string with reversed string and return result
   return s == std::string(s.rbegin(), s.rend());
}

int main()
{
   std::string test = "never odd or even";
   bool result = isPalindrome(test);
   std::cout << "\"" << test << "\" is" << (result?" ":" not ") << "a palindrome";
}
```

Output:

```
"never odd or even" is a palindrome
```

Comment: Like i asked Mattew coats, One of my classmates recommend me to use the line : While (isspace(userInput.at(userEnd), The only problem is that i do not know how to use that command, nor do i know how it works

Comment: It makes no sense to write a `while` loop to erase spaces.  As stated, to remove spaces from a string in C++ is done very simply by using `std::remove` or `std::remove_if`.   Even the name of the function tells you the purpose of it.  A `while` loop gives no context in how or what it's doing, and seriously, I have no idea what your classmate is suggesting with that loop.

Comment: ahh ! i see, thank you for the information it was very helpful i was able to make it run with this code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you remove the spaces from the string before testing if it's a palindrome? Use getline() as you are now, then remove all spaces from the input, and then do your palindrome test.

This link might be helpful for a method to remove the spaces: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-spaces-from-a-given-string/

Side note: comparing a boolean value to true like you are with `if (isPalindrome == true)` is not necessary. You can just use `if (isPalindrome)`

Comment: Thank you Matthew, it is my first time coding with c++, i am doing my homework on a website called zybooks. it allows me to input my own palindrome but once i go to submit my code to be graded it runs a set of 7 different palindromes some with spaces and others with out. That is why i am having so much trouble with the spaces in the code i have to write a line of code so that when the teachers 7 run, they run without the spaces.

Comment: Side Note: One of my classmates recommend me to use the line :                                  While (isspace(userInput.at(userEnd)                                                                            The only problem is that i do not know how to use that command, nor do i know how it works.

Comment: Hi Leo. To be clear, my recommendation was not to remove the spaces before inputting it into your program. My recommendation was to get the input with spaces included (with the getline() method), and then programmatically remove them before testing if the string is a palindrome. I believe this should suffice for your teacher's runs as well.

Comment: oh in that case, i believe i just got the code to run correctly, thank you very much ! i also had another question, what would i write in my code if i wanted the program to skip the spaces and not remove them ?